# Oxygen Builder multiple users simultaneously

Tags: wordpress, multi-user

is there a possible way to work simultaneously with multiple users on a Website without overwritting the global styles. When I'm saving my changes and defining some new CSS classes they always disappear after my partner saves his changes also.

Is there a possible way to avoid this problem?

Maybe we failed at the installation and made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxygen's site, they do support multi-user editing.

At a guess, it may be possible to apply your own hooks so things aren't auto-generated/saved.  You'd essentially create your own plugin to overwrite the functions provided by Oxygen.

How that functions, I'm not sure, but it would require "manually updating" later.

Honestly, IMO, I wouldn't try to overwrite this functionality, but instead look into local environments instead.  Create a copy of the site that all your devs can use on their local machine, and then move it on to a shared/dev/staging site.

TBH, I've found Oxygen to be a bit of a step back in the DevOps life cycle, since collaboration is a task now.

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://oxygenbuilder.com/documentation/other/multi-user-editing-edit-locking/) recommend using a single tab when working with Oxygen to avoid issues where one tab is saving older data than another, resulting in overwriting your new changes. The same scenario can occur when two or more users are working in Oxygen at the same time.

We have developed the plugin to support multiple user simultaneously.

http://collaboration.docs.oxyrealm.com

The plugin will update data and design instantly between multiple tabs of Oxygen Editor. So the overwrite issue is resolved since the data to save will be same and synced between the oxygen editor